# listview's row stretch on galaxy note emulator

Tags: android, android-layout

project have 4 drawable and layout folder(xh,h,m,l).
this is part of manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

this is whole main xml code of xhdpi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@layout/bg_repeat" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bg_header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_header"
    android:padding="0dip">
    <ImageView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/text_header" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id = "@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="2.5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is row xml for xhdpi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/test"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingRight="20dp"
android:paddingLeft="20dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_selector">

<test.TextViewPlus
    android:id="@+id/menutext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="#3D1E00"
    android:textSize="@dimen/TitleNormalXH"
    foo:customFont="Mj_Shablon.ttf"
   android:gravity="right|center_vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is galaxy note emulator setting:
dpi:285 . android version:google api level 10 (2.3.3)

and this is output:

[image]

second question: different between put android:background="@drawable/menu_selector" for row's layout ,and listview's layout ?

Comment: @nandeesh i said output is wrong and share a image link.i said it again in title of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bg_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_header">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/text_header" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id = "@+id/mainlist"
        style="@style/ListView"
        android:dividerHeight="2.5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

Row xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:dr="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/pak"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingRight="20dp"
android:paddingLeft="20dp">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_selector"
    android:gravity="center">

    <pak.TextViewPlus
        android:id="@+id/menutext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textSize="@dimen/TitleNormalM"
        android:gravity="right"
        dr:customFont="Mj_Shablon.ttf"
        android:padding="0dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and nine patch image must be like about : [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE9ly.png]

Answer (score 1):

I guess this can help:
In your adapter, in getView(...) method, after you inflate your row, use this:

```
row.setMinimumHeight(height);
```

Argument of method is in pixle you should chose your specific dp height and then convert it to  px.

Comment: let me try it,and then say what's happen ;)

Comment: tnx,but its not correct.because i do'nt want to set height in dp.i wanna image scretch to content(nine patch).